# Delete registry key and start application

Tags: c, windows

Currently, I have small exe with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    system("REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Policies\\Skype /f");

    system("start C:\\opt\\SCPort\\SkypePortable\\SkypePortable.exe");

    return 0;
}
```

It works, tut it's, of course, very far from correct implementation of necessary actions...

What is correct way? Which functions I need to read about?

Comment: See CreateProcess and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Correct in what way?  What does the above code do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows API you need to read about RegOpenKey, RegEnumKey, and RegDeleteKey to delete a registry key and about CreateProcess to start new application. See complete examples here: [Deleting a Key with Subkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724235(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Creating Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx).